# Can you skip epsilon transitions in union expression (Thompson's construction algorithm)

Tags: regex, discrete-mathematics, dfa, nfa, automaton

In the picture below can I use both NFA interchangeably? If not then why?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, they are equivalent (they recognize the same language). More formally:

First, let's give names to your states:

[image: Original DFA from Thompson's algorithm]

Now, through [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction), let's remove the epsilon transitions:

[image]

Finally, we can use any DFA minimization algorithm such as [Brzozowski's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Brzozowski.27s_algorithm) (reverse the arrows, apply powerset construction again, re-reverse the arrows) to obtain your resulting DFA.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: which tool you use?